# Tiles 3 And Java Version

Tags: tiles, apache-tiles

On the Tiles 3 Getting Started page, it claims that Java 1.6 is required. However, upon configuration, I get a NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Locale$Builder. The exact class referenced in the stacktrace is tiles-request-api-1.0.4.jar.

Locale$Builder is a Java 1.7 class. I do not currently have the option of using Java 1.7.

Does anyone know if there's a version of Tiles 3 that actually DOES run in Java 1.6?

Jason

Answer (score 0):

This was [broken](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.tiles.user/693/focus=695) in tiles-3.0.4

It has been fixed in trunk and a 3.0.5 release is to follow a tiles-request-1.0.6 release (which has just been [voted on](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.tiles.devel/713)).

If you can't wait you can use tiles-3.0.3